# Solving an equation in r

Tags: r, equation, equation-solving

Suppose I have the following equation:

```
sigmagm <- function(sigma){
  
(-sigma*t) - (alpha_h*t) - ((beta1_dot_h/beta2_h) * (exp(beta2_h*(x+t)) - exp(beta2_h*x))) - ((beta1_dot_h/beta2_h) * exp(beta2_h*x)*(1 - (1+gama) * exp(beta2_h*t))) + (alpha_dd + (1+gama) * alpha_h) * t + ((beta1_dot_dd/beta2_dd) * exp(beta2_dd * (x+t))) - (gama * (beta1_dot_h/beta2_h) * exp(beta2_h * (x+t)) * (1-(beta2_h * (t/2)))) - ((beta1_dot_dd/beta2_dd) * exp(beta2_dd * (x+(t/2))) * (1 - beta2_dd*(t/2))) - log(sigma) - log(exp((gama*alpha_h) + alpha_dd - sigma + (gama*beta1_dot_h*exp(beta2_h * (x+(t/2)))) + (beta1_dot_dd * exp(beta2_dd * (x+(t/2)))*t)) - 1) - log((gama*alpha_h) + alpha_dd - sigma + (gama * beta1_dot_h * exp(beta2_h * (x+(t/2)))) + (beta1_dot_dd*exp(beta2_dd * (x+(t/2))))) - log((1 - prev)/prev)
  
  return(sigmagm)
}
```

and I have the value of all variables except for the sigma

```
alpha_h = -0.001188
beta1_h = -5.85382
beta2_h = 0.43633
alpha_dd = -0.002006
beta1_dd = -6.24563
beta2_dd = 0.01495
beta1_dot_dd = exp(beta1_dd)
beta1_dot_h = exp(beta1_h)
prev = 0.057115867
t = 5
x = 15
gama = 0
```

How can I solve the equation to obtain the value of sigma?

I've been trying using `uniroot` and `optimise` function but I still don't get the answer. Maybe I use the wrong function?

Comment: If the equation above calculates ```sigmagm``` from these variables and ```sigma```, then is ```sigmagm``` given in this case?

Comment: `sigmagm` you provided is a function that takes a single parameter `sigma`. There is no equation to be solved here! Other variables used in the expression (not equation) are not defined within the function itself but are assumed to be defined elsewhere in the code or in the global environment.

Comment: Are you sure that function has roots? Also, you should remove the `return` instruction, all of it, for the function to make sense, like this you are returning its argument.

Comment: first you only solve an equation: eg `3x+1=4` solve for `x`. you note that you have the function value `4` and one missing parameter. in youe case, you have not provided a function value to be equated unto. how do you want to proceed?

Comment: The function appears not to have any roots. It does have a minimum value of ~18.30628 at `sigma = 0.0002687089`. Try `curve(sigmagm, 1e-6, 5e-4)` and `optimize(sigmagm, c(1e-6, 5e-4))`.

Answer (score 3):

To obtain the inverse function, we first need to obtain the domain of the `sigmagm` function. it follows that the `sigmagm` is defined within: `(0,exp(-7.575783407)]` Anything ouside of this domain produces `NA`. Notice also that between `(0, exp(-31.7064))` the function has one root while anything above `exp(-31.7064)` the function has two roots.
When doing the inversion, we note that the computer is limited with the computation of very small numbers. The range thus for the function is `(18.30267, 162)` Taking all these into account, the inverse can be computed as:

```
Inv_Sigmagm <- function(x){
  upper_limit <- exp(-7.575783407)
  fn_upper <-  sigmagm(upper_limit)
  div <- sigmagm(1.698581080212673947126e-14)
  fn <- function(i, x){
    if(i[1]>upper_limit || i[1]<=0) NA
    else abs(sigmagm(i[1]) - x)
  }
  suppressWarnings(c(optim(2e-30, fn, x = x)[[1]],
    if(x <= div) optim(upper_limit, fn, x = x)[[1]]))
  
}
```

---

Notice that for any `x` value below tha minimum, we will return the minimum while for any `x>162` we set x<-162.

Thus:

```
Inv_Sigmagm(50)
[1] 2.146653e-18
sigmagm(Inv_Sigmagm(50))
[1] 50
```

---

```
sigmagm <- function(sigma){
  alpha_h = -0.001188
  beta1_h = -5.85382
  beta2_h = 0.43633
  alpha_dd = -0.002006
  beta1_dd = -6.24563
  beta2_dd = 0.01495
  beta1_dot_dd = exp(beta1_dd)
  beta1_dot_h = exp(beta1_h)
  prev = 0.057115867
  t = 5
  x = 15
  gama = 0
  
  ((-sigma*t) - (alpha_h*t) - 
    ((beta1_dot_h/beta2_h) * (exp(beta2_h*(x+t)) - exp(beta2_h*x))) - 
    ((beta1_dot_h/beta2_h) * exp(beta2_h*x)*(1 - (1+gama) * exp(beta2_h*t))) + 
    (alpha_dd + (1+gama) * alpha_h) * t + 
    ((beta1_dot_dd/beta2_dd) * exp(beta2_dd * (x+t))) - 
    (gama * (beta1_dot_h/beta2_h) * exp(beta2_h * (x+t)) * (1-(beta2_h * (t/2)))) - 
    ((beta1_dot_dd/beta2_dd) * exp(beta2_dd * (x+(t/2))) * (1 - beta2_dd*(t/2))) - 
    log(sigma) - 
    log(exp((gama*alpha_h) + alpha_dd - sigma +
              (gama*beta1_dot_h*exp(beta2_h * (x+(t/2)))) + 
              (beta1_dot_dd * exp(beta2_dd * (x+(t/2)))*t)) - 1) -
    log((gama*alpha_h) + alpha_dd - sigma + 
          (gama * beta1_dot_h * exp(beta2_h * (x+(t/2)))) +
          (beta1_dot_dd*exp(beta2_dd * (x+(t/2))))) - 
    log((1 - prev)/prev))
  
}
```